# How to show dynamic values in ag-grid cell editor select

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I want to show dynamic drop down options for each row of ag-grid.

Suppose for each row, department might be different and based on that I plan to filter list of subjects (available option for users to select in dropdown)

Here is my code:

```
this.gridOptions.columnDefs = {
            headerName: 'Department',
            field: 'financingCurrency',
            editable: false,                            
            suppressSorting: false,
            cellClass: 'grid-align'
        },

        {
            headerName: 'Subject',
            field: 'subject',
            editable: true,
            cellEditor: 'select',
            filter: 'text',
            cellEditorParams: {
                values: this.subjects;                    
            },
            suppressSorting: false,
            cellClass: 'grid-align'
        }
}
```

I am using free version of ag-grid with Angular 2.

Does someone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to have different values in the cellEditor based on which department is selected. If that is correct, then you will likely need to do something more complicated dealing with [cellEditors](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0). Here is a [plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/MIAQIBw4J9zNXpqke26D/) that I made that checks if the name starts with a J, if so then it allows a third option.

Please refer to the [plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/MIAQIBw4J9zNXpqke26D/) for full example, as well as the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0) to make sure that you get everything imported/exported in the right places. Here is what is the key importance for you beyond what is on the docs:

```
agInit(params: any): void {
    if (params.node.data.financingCurrency == 'Your Super Department') {
        subjects = [...super options...]
    } else {
        subjects = [...different options...]
    }
}
```

`agInit` gets called any time editing is started. `params` has a complicated object, (I suggest `console.log()`ing it just to see everything that is available to you) but basically the node is referring to the row that the cell is on, and the data is the data for that row, and judging by your colDefs you can get the value of the Department from financingCurrency.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It worked.. Also how do I pass some a value in Editor component? As we just have type  cellEditorFramework: ProductEditorComponent

Answer (score -3):

try something similar :

```
  {
    headerName: ' MEDICINE NAME ', 
    field: 'medicine',
    cellEditor: 'autoComplete',
    cellEditorParams:params => {
         return  {
          'propertyRendered' : 'name',
          'rowData':  this.medicineList, 
          'columnDefs' : [{headerName: 'Medicine', field:'name'}]
      } 
    } 
  },
```

Comment: Please add more details supporting your answer. Check out this link on [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers** and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers (if there are any). [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29989121)